# Replace Variables in a .docx file with user inputted variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project that I am working on. I have a .docx template that I've created.
Within there, I have multiple variables across the whole document that need to be replaced with user-imputed information, (some variables are replaces more than once within the doc). 
I have this code that I modified from previous .txt files that I have worked with. I am not able to take the .docx file, edit the vars with user imputed info and create a new file that I can share/print. Any help would be appreciated.

I have attempted to try to use `python-docx` but alas, I have not fully understood the concept and make it work.

Sample code follows:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import fileinput

#def terms and ask user for imput
def loaDocOne():
    words = ["[clientName]","[addressLine1]","[addressLine2]","[todaysDate]","[fileNum]","[originalClient]","[refNum]","[currentBal]","]
    clientName = input('Enter Clients name: ')
    addressLine1 = input('Enter Clients Address Line 1: ')
    addressLine2 = input('Enter Clients Address Line 2: ')
    todaysDate = input('Enter Todays Date: ')
    fileNum = input('Enter File Number: ')
    originalClient = input('Enter Original Client: ')
    refNum = input('Enter Original Refrence Number: ')


    #open file
def replaceFunc():
    with open ('template.docx') as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.replace("[clientName]",clientName)
                line = line.replace("[addressLine1]",addressLine1 )
                line = line.replace("[addressLine2]",addressLine2 )
                line = line.replace("[todaysDate]",todaysDate)
                line = line.replace("[fileNum]",fileNum )
                line = line.replace("[originalClient]", originalClient)
                line = line.replace("[refNum]",refNum )



 #Find out if everything looks good to continue
def goOn():
    doYouWantToContinue = input('Does Everything Look Correct? yes/no: ')
    if doYouWantToContinue == 'yes':
        replaceFunc()
    else:
        loaDocOne()




loaDocOne()
goOn()
replaceFunc()
```

Also, Is there a way to take the outputted file and make it 'document_name_'fileNum'' with the user provided file number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `python-docx` module is the easiest way to proceed. The structure of a document opened using this module is [documented here](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and I think it's pretty easy to wrap your head around.

This code opens a document, then for each of it's paragraphs it replaces the existing text with the replaced text, using the `str.replace` function that automatically replaces all occurrences of some string.

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document('document.docx')

replacements = {
    '%replace_me_1%': 'New text 1',
    '%replace_me_2%': 'New text 2'
    }

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    for key in replacements:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(key, replacements[key])

doc.save('document.docx')
```

---

Saving the file with a new name should be quite easy:

```
file_suffix = input()
doc.save('document_' + file_suffix + '.docx')
```

Comment: Is there a way to have 'New Text 1' Be something that I would be able to input? Or is just something that can only be changed in code?
Within the document, does that allow me to change one specific variable? Or does it change multiple words/paragraphs? ty :D

Comment: You can input some variable, say `dateofbirth = input()` and then create the replacements dict using that `replacements = {'%DOB%': dateofbirth, ...}`.

Comment: Or, you are also able to add to the dictionary after its creation. For example: `replacements = {}`, and then somewhere later in your code `replacements['%DOB%'] = input('Please enter your date of birth:')`

Comment: Hmmm. Thank you!. I'll try this tomorrow and I will tell you how it goes! Thank you so much.

Comment: Another question, With this option, how would I write the variables within the word doc. Is it '%DOB%' as well? or is it something different. Thank you

Comment: Yes, whatever text is in the dict key (`%DOB%`) is also what will be replaced in the .docx.

Comment: Also. When I save the doc file, and then open it, it doesnt keep the style formatting that was previous in the other document. Any bold or highleted text just transforms to normal TNR font 12. Is there a way to keep the formatting when I save the doc?